# Expressing the roots of a cubic as polynomials in one root

Tags: polynomials, cubics, splitting-field

All roots of $8x^3-6x+1$ are real. (*)

The discriminant of $8x^3-6x+1$ is $5184=72^2$ and so the splitting field of $8x^3-6x+1$ has degree $3$.

Therefore, all three roots can be expressed as polynomials in any one given root.

Indeed, if $a$ is a root, then the others are $2a^2-1$ and $-2a^2-a+1$.

> This can be easily checked. But how can we find these expressions in the first place?

I've tried this: let $b,c$ be the other roots. Then from Vieta's formulas we get $$b+c=-a, \qquad bc=-\dfrac{1}{8a}$$

The corresponding quadratic has discriminant $3-3a^2$ but it is not at all clear that this is the square of a polynomial in $a$. (It is $(4 a^2+a-2
)^2=(b-c)^2$, as it should be.) I'm stuck here.

> More generally, is there an algorithm that
>   given a cubic with integer coefficients and
>   having real splitting field of degree $3$,
>   expresses all three roots as polynomials in any one given root?

(*) From the triple-angle formula $\sin (3\theta) = - 4\sin^3\theta + 3\sin\theta$ when $\sin (3\theta) = 1/2$, these roots are $\sin(10^\circ)$, $\sin(50^\circ)$, $\sin(-70^\circ)$, but perhaps this is immaterial here.

Comment: Undetermined coefficients? The polynomials we need are at most degree 2.

Comment: @hardmath, right, but I haven't tried undetermined coefficients because we'll get nonlinear equations for the coefficients...

Comment: The roots are $a,g(a),g(g(a))$ for $g(x)=2x^2-1$. So the question is how to find $g$, both for the particular equation I gave and also in general. Note that $g(g(g(a)))=a$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794942/express-one-root-of-depressed-cubic-equation-via-another-and-square-root-of-disc seems relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the answers in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794942/express-one-root-of-depressed-cubic-equation-via-another-and-square-root-of-disc), I'm able to finish the general case.

Let $x^3+px+q$ be a cubic with rational coefficients and having real splitting field of degree $3$. Let its roots be $a,b,c$. Then
$$b+c=-a, \qquad bc=-\dfrac{q}{a}$$
and $b,c$ are the roots of the quadratic
$$
h(x)=(x-b)(x-c)=x^2+ax-\dfrac{q}{a}
$$
The discriminant of $h$ is $b-c$. Now comes the nice idea from [those answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794942/express-one-root-of-depressed-cubic-equation-via-another-and-square-root-of-disc):
$$
d=(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)=h(a)(b-c)
$$
where $d^2=-4p^3-27q^2$ is the discriminant of the original cubic. The hypothesis on the cubic implies that $d$ is rational. Therefore,
$$
b-c = \dfrac{d}{h(a)}
$$
To write this as a polynomial in $a$, we solve the linear system on $A,B,C$ implied by
$$
d=(Aa^2+Ba+C)h(a)=(Aa^2+Ba+C)(2a^2-\dfrac{q}{a})
$$
or
$$
ad=(Aa^2+Ba+C)(2a^3-q)=(Aa^2+Ba+C)(-2pa-3q)
$$
The solution is
$$
A=-\dfrac{6p}{d},
\quad
B=\dfrac{9q}{d},
\quad
C=-\dfrac{4p^2}{d}
$$
which gives
$$
b,c = -\dfrac{a}{2} \pm \dfrac{1}{2}(Aa^2+Ba+C)
$$

Comment: Nice! Now I need to figure out a way of turning this into an exercise for my course :-)