# What are the $\Bbb Q$-automorphisms of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ with $\alpha$ a root of $x^3-3x^2+3$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I know the polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ and the roots are real irrational. A $\Bbb Q$-automorphism $\sigma:\Bbb Q(\alpha)\to \Bbb Q(\alpha)$ is determined by $\sigma(\alpha)$, which is also a root of the polynomial. My problem is finding out if the other roots are also in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$. If the other roots are $\beta, \gamma$, then I set the system
$3=\alpha+\beta+\gamma, -3=\alpha\beta\gamma$. For example, clearing $\beta$, I obtain

$\beta=\frac{3-\alpha}{2}\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2-6\alpha+9+\frac{12}{\alpha}}$

(A solution can be with the positive square root, then the negative one is $\gamma$)

I don't know how to conclude if this $\beta$ is in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ or not.

I tried to search similar problems but they apply results I don't know, like using the discriminant or splitting stuff. With the current theory I have in lessons I only have very basics tools.

Comment: What is $r$ in that formula for $\beta$?

Comment: Have you heard about Galois groups? Particularly their relation to the discriminant?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2017810/11619). Hint: $x=y+a$ for some integer $a$.

Comment: @aschepler sorry, that was a mistake, I edited it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I said in the end I'm not working with discriminant with the theory I have in lessons

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767252/expressing-the-roots-of-a-cubic-as-polynomials-in-one-root

Comment: That's ok. I have taught this course a few times. And the most useful answer really depends on what has been covered, which is why I asked. Looks like blamocur (+1) picked up on the hints. That answer is likely the most helpful to you.

Comment: You can use the trigonometric solution by substituting $x=1+2\cos t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pure cheating: I browsed the referenced links and transformed their answers to fit this problem:

$$
P(x) = x^3 - 3x^2+3
$$

$$
P(\alpha) = 0
$$

$$
\beta = R(\alpha) = -\alpha^2 + \alpha + 3
$$

$$
P(\beta) = P (R(\alpha)  = P ( -\alpha^2 + \alpha + 3)
$$
$$
= - \alpha^{6} + 3 \alpha^{5} + 3 \alpha^{4} - 11 \alpha^{3} - 3 \alpha^{2} + 9 \alpha + 3  =
$$
$$
= \left( \alpha^{3} - 3 \alpha^{2} + 3 \right)
\left( -\alpha^{3} + 3 \alpha + 1 \right) =
P(\alpha)
\left( -\alpha^{3} + 3 \alpha + 1 \right)
 = 0
$$

Which means that $\beta$ is a root of $P$ and $\beta \in \mathbb Q(\alpha)$

Comment: How is the polynomial $R(\alpha)$ obtained?

Comment: @AarónDavidArroyoTorres I derived it from other posts, which use discriminants. The goal is to find $R$ such that $P(R(x))$ is divisible by $P(x)$. I wonder if it is possible to solve the resulting equations for the coefficients of $R$, and thus avoid using discriminants?

Comment: Yes, you could suppose $\beta = A \alpha^2 + B \alpha + C$, then multiply out $P(\beta)=0$, reduce the $\alpha^4$ and $\alpha^3$ terms using $\alpha^3 = 3 \alpha^2-3$, and finally solve a system of three equations in $A, B, C$. (Also, I wouldn't call learning techniques from other examples then applying them to a similar problem cheating!)

Comment: @aschepler  The equations I get for A,B,C are quite hairy though :(

Comment: Quite. Which is why the Galois theorems are nice to have...