# Finding roots \ if any in Q[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find all c $ \in Q\ if\ any\ s.t. f(c)=0$
Where i) $f(x)=4x^4-2x^3-2x^2-x-1$ 
ii) $f(x)=8x^3-6x-1$

Okay so what I have been trying is the rational root test.
In i the possible roots are: +-$({1,1/2, 1/4 })$ but none of them are roots.
Then I can see that Eisenstein criterion is not working as well. So I tried to see if it is irreducible in $Z_{p}\ with \ Z_{2}$. Hence if this is the case I could conclude that it is irreducible in $Q_[x]$, but it is reducible since in $Z_{2} \ i)=x+1$
which is reducible in $Z_{2}$... so now I am quite stuck my approach for ii) was the same but also got stuck

Comment: What's the question?  Is it reducibility or roots?  In any case, you can't use $p=2$ for Eisenstein (for the first one) as the lead coefficient is $0\pmod 2$.

Comment: I have to find f(c)=0 if any

Comment: Reducibility should not confused with solutions, I think the OP is trying to find roots.

Comment: Then why are you talking about Eisenstein?  The rational root theorem is all you need.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  The header clearly address reducibility, as does much of the body.  That's a much harder question then just finding roots.  (worth noting:  for cubics, finding rational roots is the same as deciding reducibility, but not for higher degree).

Comment: Okay the edit is done now.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can just use rational root test, and then I can see that none of the possible roots are roots?

Comment: Exactly!  That's what the rational root theorem says.

Comment: Okay, I just got confused with irreducibility and roots. I was thinking that if you have roots, then it must be reducible. But if there is no roots then it is irreducible

Comment: @Djhoe Specifically, there are no **integer** roots.

Comment: ok thanks so for the ii) +-(1,1/2,1/4,1/8) are no roots $ \implies $ no roots exists as well

Comment: BTW, the roots of $8x^3-6x-1$ are $\sin(10^\circ)$, $\sin(50^\circ)$, $\sin(-70^\circ)$, all irrational. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767252/expressing-the-roots-of-a-cubic-as-polynomials-in-one-root