# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}$ normal where $\gamma$ is a zero of $p(t) = t^3 - 3t^2 +3$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}$  be the extension where  $\gamma$ is a zero of $p(t) = t^3 - 3t^2 +3$

I'm having trouble figuring out if this extension is normal or not. I know that if I can show $$p(t) =t^3-3t^2+3 = (t-\gamma)(t^2+(\gamma-3)t+(\gamma^2-3\gamma))$$ does not split over $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}$, then I'm done (since if $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}$ was normal, then since $p(t)$ has a zero in $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}$, $p(t)$ must split) or alternatively, if it does split, $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}$ is the splitting field of $p(t)$ and since the extension is finite, $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma):\mathbb{Q}$  is then normal. I'm just stuck on proving if it splits or not. I tried to plug in the quadratic into the quadritic formula but it didn't seem to lead me anywhere.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you computed the discriminant of $p(t)$?

Comment: If the importance of Lord Shark's suggestion is not clear to you, you can, instead, try and show that if $\gamma$ is one zero of $p(t)$ then $\gamma^2-2\gamma$ is another.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, how did you find that polynomial? (see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767252/expressing-the-roots-of-a-cubic-as-polynomials-in-one-root)

Comment: @lhf The discriminant was a "giveaway" to the following:
$$p(x+1)=x^3-3x+1.$$ That I happened to know to be the minimal polynomial of $2\cos(2\pi/9)$, and therefore subject to the "famous" rule: if $r$ is a zero, then so is $r^2-2$. So I simply "translated by one" the automorphism $r\mapsto r^2-2$. The zeros of $p(t)$ are $1+2\cos(2k\pi/9)$ with $k=1,2,4$. Admittedly I was also lucky. Possibly there are many elements from this same field sharing the discriminant of their minimal polynomial with the field.