# Cyclic property of the root of a cubic polynomial

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, cubics

Let $f(x) = x^3 - 3x + 1$. Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ be the roots of $f$ with $\alpha > \beta > \gamma$. Let $g(x) = x^2 - 2$. We see that $\beta = g(\alpha)$, $\gamma = g(\beta)$ and $\alpha = g(\gamma)$ by calculation using $f$.

Why does this cyclic property hold? What is the relation between $f$ and $g$? Could you tell me its background or generalization?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767252/expressing-the-roots-of-a-cubic-as-polynomials-in-one-root

Comment: @lhf Thank you for your amazing answer in the URL above. This solves my question, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any cubic polynomial $f(x)$ with three distinct roots $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ you can find a quadratic polynomial $g(x)$ such that $g(\alpha)=\beta$, $g(\beta)=\gamma$, $g(\gamma)=\alpha$; it's just the matter of assuming $g(x)=rx^2+sx+t$ and solving three linear equations on coefficients $r$, $s$, $t$. What may be interesting is a method to find such a polynomial when you don't know the roots.

Let $\alpha$ be one of three distinct roots of $f(x) = x^3+bx^2+cx+d$. Then we can factorize $(x-\alpha)$ from $f(x)$ to get
$$ f(x) = (x-\alpha)\big(x^2 + (b + \alpha) x +(\alpha^2 + b\alpha + c)\big) $$
which means that the other two roots of $f(x)$ are the roots of the polynomial
$$ h(x) = x^2 + (b + \alpha) x +(\alpha^2 + b\alpha + c)$$
If we are looking for a binomial $g(x) = rx^2+sx+t$ such that $g(\alpha)$ is another root of $f(x)$, i.e. $g(\alpha)$ is a root of $h(x)$ , we know that it must satisfy
$$ 0 = h(g(\alpha)) = g(\alpha)^2 + (b + \alpha) g(\alpha) +(\alpha^2 + b\alpha + c)$$
\begin{align} 0 &= r^2 \alpha^4 + (2rs+r)\alpha^3 +  (s^2+2rt+br+s+1)\alpha^2 + \\
&\qquad +(2st+bs+t+b) \alpha + (t^2+bt+c) \end{align}
Remembering that $f(\alpha) =0$, that is
$$ \alpha^3 = -b\alpha^2-c\alpha-d$$
from which it follows that
$$ \alpha^4 = -b\alpha^3-c\alpha^2-d\alpha = (b^2-c)\alpha^2+(bc-d)\alpha + bd$$
that condition can be written as
\begin{align} 0 &= (r^2b^2-r^2c-2rsb+s^2+2rt+s+1)\alpha^2 +\\
&\qquad + (r^2bc-r^2d-2rsc-rc+2st+bs+t+b) \alpha + \\
&\qquad + (r^2bd-2rsd-rd + t^2+bt+c) \end{align}
If we want this to be true no matter which root $\alpha$ of $f(x)$ we start with, we need
\begin{align} 0 &= r^2b^2-r^2c-2rsb+s^2+2rt+s+1\\
0&= r^2bc-r^2d-2rsc-rc+2st+bs+t+b \\
0&= r^2bd-2rsd-rd + t^2+bt+c \end{align}
which is a set of second-degree polynomial equations on $r$,$s$, $t$ with $b$, $c$, $d$ being known parameters. It is complicated, but it has some solution (sometimes in complex numbers). For $f(x)=x^3-3x+1$, that is for $b=0$, $c=-3$, $d=1$, it can be checked that $r=1$, $s=0$, $t=-2$ is one of the solutions, and this solution gives you $g(x)=x^2-2$ from your question. Either way, if we find a solution to these equations we find a polynomial $g(x)$ which transforms each root of $f(x)$ into another.

Since this set of equations can have many solutions, we may get various polynomials $g(x)$, some of which may produce roots in a cyclic way, while others don't. For example, for $f(x)=x^3-3x^2+2x$ (with roots $0$, $1$ and $2$)  we can find that $g(x)=x^2-3x+2$ satisfies these equations, but doesn't transform the roots in a cyclic way (we have $g(0)=2$, $g(1)=g(2)=0$). There are five other solutions that transform the roots in non-cyclic way, but there are also two solutions that do that in a cyclic way: $g(x)=-\frac32x^2+\frac52x+1$ and $g(x)=\frac32x^2-\frac72 x+2$. My conjecture is that for any cubic polynomial with three distinct roots there will always be 8 solutions of the equations I derived, two of which will transform the roots in a cyclic way (in two directions). For example the polynomial that rotates the roots of $f(x)=x^3-3x+1$ in the oposite way to $x^2-2$ is $g(x)=-x^2-x+2$.

This method should work for polynomials $f$ of any degree $n$, though it quickly grows in complexity and in general it requires to solve a set of $n$ polynomial equations of degree $n-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your great article. Elementary and powerful argument. Another method will give us two solutions that transform the roots in a cyclic way. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767252/expressing-the-roots-of-a-cubic-as-polynomials-in-one-root I am interested in expanding your method to choose these two solutions among eight.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is factually incorrect: see the comments below.

---

Let $a$ be any root of $f(x)$. Then $a^3 - 3a + 1 = 0 \Rightarrow a^2 - 3 = -1/a \Rightarrow a^2 - 2 = -1/a +1$. Thus $g(a) = -1/a + 1$.

Let us find $g(g(g(a)))$, which is  $g(g(-1/a + 1)) = g\left(-\frac{1}{-1/a+1} + 1 \right) = g\left(\frac{-a}{-1+a} + \frac{-1+a}{-1+a} \right) $ $ = g\left(\frac{-1}{-1+a}\right) = \frac{-1}{-1/(-1+a)} +1 = -1+a+1=a$. From this process, the roots of $f(x)$ in terms of $a$ are $a$, $-\frac{1}{a} + 1$ and $\frac{-1}{1+a}$. This means that cycling any root three times through $g(x)$ gives the original root, and these are the only three roots, since a cubic polynomial has at most three real roots.

The tricky part is the condition that $\alpha > \beta > \gamma$, where $\alpha$ is the largest root. In other words, how do we know that the cycling order isn't actually $\alpha, \gamma, \beta$? Observe that $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$, $(\beta, \gamma, \alpha)$ and $(\gamma, \alpha, \beta)$ represent the same cyclic permutation, and the other permutation $(\alpha, \gamma, \beta)$ also makes up three permutations, and because there are only $3! = 6$ in total, these are the only permutations.

So if the other permutation $(\gamma, \beta, \alpha)$ is true, then $\beta > \alpha$ (any other inequality would also hold for $(\gamma, \alpha, \beta)$), or $-\frac{1}{\alpha} + 1 > \alpha$, which leads to $\alpha < 0$ (*). By [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), $f(-x) = -x^3 + 3x + 1$ has one sign change, hence there is only one negative root. However, since there are three real roots from the question, the other two roots are positive ($0$ is not a root). Therefore $\alpha$ is not the largest root: contradiction, and the cycling order is $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Hence proved.

---

(*) Rearrange to get $\frac{1}{a} < 1- a$ as the inequality sign flips. You will have to split it into positive and negative cases to prove this algebraically, but this can be shown by a sketch.

---

I haven't actually shown that the values that $g(x)$ cycles through are the roots of $f(x)$! Vieta's formulas can be used to do this: prove that $a + g(a) + g(g(a)) = 0$, and do the same for $\alpha \beta + \beta \gamma + \gamma \alpha$ and $\alpha \beta \gamma$.

Comment: For a generalisation, check out some functions which satisfy $f(f(f(x))) = x$ on [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24g%5Cleft(g%5Cleft(g%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cright)%3Dx%24&p=1). If you set this equal to a polynomial, you can get other polynomials such as the $x^3-3x+1$ you mentioned.

Comment: So if $f(x) = x^3+ u x+ v$, then what would $ g(x)$ be in terms of $(u,v)$ to be cyclic ?

Comment: Good question, but I suggest you ask it as a separate question. One of the examples given in Approach0 was $y = \frac{3+x}{1-x}$.

Comment: Asked the same..shall edit the  question to be suitable.

Comment: Let $h(x) = -1/x + 1$. You showed that $h(h(h(x))) = x$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0, 1 \}$. Then, you said that
"From this process, the roots of $f(x)$ in terms of $a$ are $a$, $-\frac{1}{a} + 1$ and $\frac{-1}{1+a}$." Why can you say this?

Comment: In the steps before that line, $g(a)$ is replaced by $-\frac{1}{a} + 1$ in $g(g(-\frac{1}{a} + 1))$.

Comment: I don't get it yet. Could you show me that, if $a$ is a root of $f$, then $-1/a + 1$ is a root of $f$, using $h(h(h(x))) = x$?

Comment: $g(a) = -\frac{1}{a} + 1$. Then $g(g(a)) = g(-\frac{1}{a} + 1) = -\frac{1}{-1/a + 1} + 1 = \frac{-a}{-1 + a} + 1 = \frac{-a}{-1+a} + \frac{-1+a}{-1+a} = \frac{-1}{-1+a}$. Then $g(g(g(a)))$ is $g$ of $g(g(a))$ or $g(\frac{-1}{-1+a}) = -\frac{1}{-1/(-1+a)} + 1 = -1+a + 1 = a$.

Comment: Why does it hold that $g(-1/a + 1) = - \frac{1}{-1/a + 1} + 1$ since $g(x) = x^2 - 2$ ? Are you showing that $h(h(h(x))) = x$ ?

Comment: Are you happy with the fact that if $a$ is a root of $f(x)=x^3-x+1$, then $a^2 - 2 = -1/a + 1$? Then since $g(x) = x^2-2$ from the question, then $g(a) = a^2-2$, so $g(a) = -1/a + 1$.

Comment: I can see that $g(a) = -1/a + 1$ holds if $a$ is a root of $f$, but it does not mean that $g(x) = -1/x + 1$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. I am wondering why $g(-1/a + 1) = - \frac{1}{-1/a + 1} + 1$ holds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121067/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-kazune-takahashi).