# Order $3$ linear transforms invariating a binary cubic form

Tags: cubics, invariant-theory, roots-of-cubics

Consider $P(x,y)$ a homogenous polynomial of degree $3$ in two variables (a  binary cubic). To it we associate first the $2\times 2$ matrix

$$\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Hess}(P) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\left( \begin{matrix}  \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x \partial y } \\   \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y \partial x } & \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2 }   \end{matrix} \right)$$
with entries linear forms in $x$, $y$, and then

$$D = \det (\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Hess}(P))= (x, y) \cdot M \cdot (x,y)^t$$  a quadratic form in $x$, $y$, where $M$ is a uniquely defined symmetric matrix (with constant entries). The matrix
$$N \colon = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)\cdot M $$

is a matrix of trace $0$ (since $M$ is symmetric).  Let also $\Delta$ be the discriminant of the binary form $P(x,y)$ ( which equals the [discriminant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialDiscriminant.html) of the polynomial $P(x,1)$)

Show that the $2\times 2 $ matrix

$$T = -\frac{1}{2} I_2 + \frac{N}{\sqrt{\Delta}}$$

is a transformation of order $3$ invariating $P$, that is

$$P(T\cdot \left ( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right)) = P(\left ( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right))$$

Notes:

1. The discriminant $\Delta$ of $P$ can also be defined by the equality
   $N^2 = -\frac{3}{4} \Delta \cdot I_2$  so indeed $T$ is of order $3$ (with characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1$)
2. Notice that $T^2 = - \frac{1}{2} I_2 - \frac{N}{\sqrt{\Delta}}$, so we can choose any determination of the square root $\sqrt{\Delta}$.
3. We get the expression of the roots of the cubic in terms of one root. That is, if $x$ a root, then $T \cdot x$, $T^2 \cdot x$ are the other two roots, where $T$ is seen as a [homographic transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)
4. Related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681876/homographic-relation-between-two-roots-of-a-cubic)
5. Probably a classical result, so provided as a [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Here $$P(\left ( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right))=P(x,y)?$$

Comment: @Leox: yes, we indentify a pair with a column vector